# .GetType().GetProperties() returns properties in different order

Tags: c#, properties, system.reflection, getproperties

I want to check our configuration file and see if it is the same as if I were to create a new configuration file. This method is called GetConfig().

After some hours I noticed that if I save my configuration file and then call GetConfig it works, but if I close the program start it up and load my configuration file in and call GetConfig() it returns my properties in a different order.

Below you can see what I mean, property **b** is an object of a class. There are more than 3 properties, but I only wanted to give a small example:

```
- - - - - - - - -- - - - - - --   S A V E   C O N F I G
 - - - - - - -- -   G E T   C O N F I G
1 Field: a
1 Field: b
1 Field: c
```

and the next config object it has to save.

```
1 Field: a
1 Field: b
1 Field: c
```

When I load the config on the same instance

```
 - - - -- - - - - - - - - -- -  A R E   E Q U A L
 - - - - - - -- -   G E T   C O N F I G
1 Field: a
1 Field: b
1 Field: c
```

next config object

```
1 Field: a
1 Field: b
1 Field: c
```

However when I load my config when I restart the program I get this:

```
- - - -- - - - - - - - - -- -  A R E   E Q U A L
 - - - - - - -- -   G E T   C O N F I G
1 Field: a
1 Field: b   <-- correct
1 Field: c
```

2nd object

```
1 Field: a
1 Field: c
1 Field: b   <-- should be 2nd.
```

So when I try to compare both configuration files they do not match.
Has anybody any experience with this?

```
foreach (var field in channel.GetType().GetProperties())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(channel.ChannelNumber + " Field: " + field.Name);
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Ordering the field names alphabetically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make any assumption about the order of return values of `Type.GetProperties`, see what [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> The GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular
>   order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not
>   depend on the order in which properties are returned, because that
>   order varies.

If you want an specific order, you should make your code order the collection returned.

Comment: @SHEePYTaGGeRNeP you should make this answer as accepted.