# RODBC query returns fields in different order

Tags: r, database, azure, select, rodbc

I have a script that runs a function on many databases. It has been working correctly up to now, but today, it returned the fields of a new db I just built in a very strange order. This is the order of the fields in the db (Azure):

```
ID, IndNum,CorpCode,IndName,Type,LOP_Tar,Active,UpisBetter,LOPisCumm
```

The script tries to download that full table. This is how I do that from R:

```
Q <- 'SELECT * FROM XXXX'
T <- sqlQuery(channel, Q, rows_at_time = 5)
names(T)
[1] "ID"         "Active"     "UpIsBetter" "LOPisCumm"  "IndNum"          "CorpCode"   "IndName"    "Type"      
[9] "LOP_Tar"
```

So it's returning the fields in the following order: `1,7:9,2:6`. Why?

Now, two things are special about THIS database. 1) it's in Spanish, and 2) It has less fields than it's sister databases. As a sanity check, I just reran one of the other dbs with the same code, and it perfectly gives the field names in order... Anyone know what's going on? Is it related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33365036/gettype-getproperties-returns-properties-in-different-order)?

If `SELECT *` doesn't give a reproducible result.... I need to reconsider some things about my life...

Comment: Is any part of the data mismatched, does the data read into R match the original db? If the columns are getting rearranged it may be a result of another issue, perhaps `NULL` values in the first rows of the db?

Comment: mismatched how? The code I pasted is the first that R is seeing. No `NULL` values in any row.

Comment: I guess I should ask; does the data read into R balance to the data in the database? Or, is there any loss of information happening when reading in the data? Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Oh, IC. Yeah, the data is correct... there is no loss nor corruption. Only the fields are returned randomly